# How can I get Ajax to work with ColdFusion using the Facebook FBML API?

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, coldfusion, fbml

I am trying to make a Facebook FMBL application for a client, not iframe or Facebook connect application. I am having trouble using a [ColdFusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColdFusion) proxy and jQuery for my synchronous data connections.

I know how to use it for typical web pages, but the Facebook version is incredibly difficult to work with. I understand that jQuery cannot be used but what about a ColdFusion proxy or another alternative? I also am familar with using JSON so if there is anything you could suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe examining a couple of the RIAForge ColdFusion Facebook apps would help?

[CFFacebook](http://cffacebook.riaforge.org/)

[Facebook Starter kit](http://fbmlstarter.riaforge.org/)

Otherwise it always helps to see some code